# How do I reset the scene?

Tags: customization, scene

Coming from Max I'm having a really hard time learning Blender (even with the 3dsMax Blender plugin that I activated). I want to reset the scene to default like 3ds Max File -> Reset. How can I do that in Blender, if that's even possible? Not reset preferences, not erase my settings, just reset the scene. Thanks.

Comment: File->New->General

Comment: Ah, that was it! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the top menu click on
File->New->General